# Finding and removing duplicates within WP Arrays

Tags: php, array, categories

I'm looking to see if it's possible to find and remove duplicates from the arrays generated below. I've tried `array_unique` `array_merge` and they haven't worked.

```
$category = get_the_category();
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
```

As an example, there is a potential that the word "Apparel" may appear in both Category and Tag for the post. With the "raw" method above, Apparel would appear twice in my output. I'm only looking to include it once. At this point in time, I believe it is ok if both lists are merged and all words are part of 1 output.

Example: `%23Apparel %23Auto %23Mens`

Then, once the output is generated, I need to add HTML URLEncode %23 to the beginning of each word.

Would appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to collect the category+tag names into the output, you can try this

```
<?php 
global $post;
$words=array();

$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $words[]="%23".$tag->name;
}

$cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
foreach($cats as $cat){
    $words[]="%23".$cat->name;
}

$words=array_unique($words);
echo implode(" ",$words);
?>
```

Comment: Worked great except for one thing. The implode ignores the first word in the string. Is there a way to have the %23 apply to all?

Comment: yes sure, you can do this `echo "%23".implode(" %23",$words);` in the previous revision of the answer or use the updated answer.

Comment: The revised answer works great. I was trying to take your original code and add a `foreach` onto the $words array and was failing. Thank you!